# how to load JWPlayer in web page

Tags: html, video, jwplayer

I have page i want to play video in JWPlayer here is the code which i am using which i got from net

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>

     <video height="270" width="480" id="myVideo">
     <source src="/static/bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="/static/bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
     </video>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     jwplayer("myVideo").setup({
     modes: [
    { type: 'html5' },
    { type: 'flash', src: '/jwplayer/player.swf' }
    ]
    });
  </script>
```

It does not show anything and from where to get jwplayer/jwplayer.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would download the JW Player from - http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/download/

And then get started here - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28833/quick-start-guide